# ¿Que representan estas funciones Nodo::Nodo(), Nodo(int), Nodo(Nodo &)?

Tags: c++, lista, punteros, diseño-de-clases, nodos

Estuve viendo el código que me paso un profesor de Nodos y mi duda es que representan y que hacen las funciones que están marcadas en el código.

Esta `Nodo::Nodo()`
Esta `Nodo::Nodo(int dato)`
Esta `Nodo::Nodo(Nodo &nodo)`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Nodo{
private:
    int dato;
    Nodo * siguiente;
public:
    Nodo();
    Nodo(int);
    Nodo(Nodo &);
    ~Nodo();
    int getdato();
    void setdato(int);
    Nodo *getsiguiente();
    void setsiguiente(Nodo *);
};
Nodo::Nodo(){//-----------------------------MARCA1
    this->dato=0;
    siguiente=NULL;
}
Nodo::Nodo(int dato){//-----------------------------MARCA2
    this->dato=dato;
    siguiente=NULL;
}
Nodo::Nodo(Nodo &nodo){//-----------------------------MARCA3
    this->dato=nodo.dato;
    this->siguiente=nodo.siguiente;
}
Nodo::~Nodo(){
}
int Nodo::getdato(){
    return dato;
}
void Nodo::setdato(int dato){
    this->dato=dato;
}
Nodo *Nodo::getsiguiente(){
    return this->siguiente;
}
void Nodo::setsiguiente(Nodo *siguiente){
    this->siguiente=siguiente;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son respectivamente:

1. El constructor por defecto del objeto `Nodo`.
2. Un constructor del objeto `Nodo` que recibe un entero (`int`).
3. El constructor de copia del objeto `Nodo`.

El constructor es una función especial con características especiales, se puede distinguir fácilmente porque no devuelve ningún valor y tiene el **mismo** nombre que el objeto al que pertenece.

El constructor por defecto, es el constructor que se usa cuando se crea un objeto sin pasarle parámetros o con una lista de parámetros vacía:

```
Nodo a;   // Constructor por defecto de Nodo.
Nodo b{}; // Constructor por defecto de Nodo.
Nodo c(); // Constructor por defecto de Nodo.
```

Si al constructor le añades parámetros, harás que el objeto sea construible pasando esos parámetros:

```
void funcion(Nodo n)
{
    std::cout << "Recibimos un nodo\n";
}

Nodo d(1);
Nodo e{1};
Nodo f = 1;
funcion(1);
```

Todos los ejemplos anteriores construyen un nodo con el valor `1`. Son especialmente relevantes los últimos casos en que creamos un `Nodo` igualándolo a un entero (`int`) explícito y llamamos a una función que recibe un `Nodo` como parámetro pero en lugar de proveer un `Nodo` le pasamos un entero (`int`). Estos constructores con un sólo parámetro también son llamados "*Constructor de conversión*" porque (en el ejemplo) permiten convertir un entero (`int`) a un `Nodo`.

Finalmente el constructor de copia permite copiar una instancia de `Nodo`:

```
Nodo g = a;
Nodo h{a};
Nodo i(a);
```

En todos los casos anteriores, los `Nodo` construidos serán una copia de la instancia de `Nodo` llamada `a`.

---

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. Dentro del objeto, no es necesario preceder `this->` para referirse a las variables miembro:

   ```
    Nodo::Nodo() {
        dato = 0;
        siguiente = NULL;
    }
   ```
2. La macro `NULL` se reemplaza con un `0`, es un remanente de [c](/questions/tagged/c) cuyo uso se desaconseja en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), en su lugar debe usarse el literal de puntero nulo `nullptr`:

   ```
    Nodo::Nodo() {
        dato = 0;
        siguiente = nullptr;
    }
   ```
3. Puedes inicializar las variables miembro en el punto de declaración, si lo haces podrás marcar el constructor como `default` para que el compilador haga el trabajo de generarlo y así te ahorras tener que definirlo:

   ```
    class Nodo{
    private:
        int dato = 0;
        Nodo * siguiente = nullptr;
    public:
        Nodo() = default; // No se necesita definir, se encarga el compilador.
        /* Resto del código. */
    };
   ```
4. Si quieres prohibir la conversión incontrolada de entero (`int`) a `Nodo`, puedes marcar el constructor como explícito, de esa manera sólo podrás construir un `Nodo` con un entero `int` si lo especificas, no por medio de una conversión:

   ```
    class Nodo{
    private:
        int dato = 0;
        Nodo * siguiente = nullptr;
    public:
        explicit Nodo(int); // Constructor explícito
        /* Resto del código. */
    };

    void funcion(Nodo n){};

    Nodo a = 1;       // Error, el constructor es explícito.
    Nodo b = Nodo(1); // Correcto, construido explícitamente.
    funcion(1);       // Error, el constructor es explícito.
    Funcion(Nodo(1)); // Correcto, construido explícitamente.
    funcion({1});     // Error, el constructor es explícito.
    Funcion(Nodo{1}); // Correcto, construido explícitamente.
   ```
5. Es una buen práctica que los constructores de copia reciban el parámetro de entrada como referencia constante ya que la copia no modifica (ni debe modificar) el original.

   ```
    class Nodo{
    private:
        int dato = 0;
        Nodo * siguiente = nullptr;
    public:
        Nodo(const Nodo &); // Constructor de copia, parámetro de entrada constante.
        /* Resto del código. */
    };
   ```
6. Puedes usar la lista de inicialización del constructor:

   ```
    Nodo::Nodo(int dato) :
        dato{dato}
    {}
    Nodo::Nodo(const Nodo &nodo) :
        dato{nodo.dato},
        siguiente{nodo.siguiente}
    {}
   ```

   En la lista de inicialización del constructor sólo puedes mencionar miembros del objeto, por lo tanto no hay ambigüedad en los nombres y no necesitas el `this` aunque el argumento y la variable miembro se llamen igual. Si inicializaste las variables miembro en el lugar de declaración, no necesitarás inicializarlas de nuevo en el constructor.
7. Si el destructor no va a tener código, no lo definas ni lo declares.
8. Es una buena práctica que las funciones de lectura de datos deben sean constantes.

   ```
    class Nodo{
    private:
        int dato = 0;
        Nodo * siguiente = nullptr;
    public:
        Nodo();
        Nodo(int);
        Nodo(Nodo &);
        ~Nodo();
        int getdato() const; // No modifica datos, es constante.
        void setdato(int);
        Nodo *getsiguiente() const; // No modifica datos, es constante.
        void setsiguiente(Nodo *);
    };
   ```

Comment: Hola, me puedes dar tu correo electronico porfa??

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas mis datos de contacto?

Answer (score 0):

El primero es la definición del constructor predeterminado (sin parámetros); el segundo es una sobrecarga del constructor con el parámetro int dato; y el tercero es el constructor de copia.

Comment: También podrías ejemplificar con código para que quede clara tu respuesta.